# Curl 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: api, curl, post, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to test my endpoint with curl and getting a 415:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:5001/api/countries/import" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Authorization: Bearer "$API_TOKEN \
--data @/D:/_countries.json
```

Response:

```
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"0HLTFOME7T990:00000001"}
```

And here's my .net core endpoint:

```
// POST api/countries/import
[HttpPost]
[Route("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Import(IFormFile file)
{
    ...
}
```

Btw, I have no problem with this endpoint in postman although it's generated code doesn't work for me (the response is the same):

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:5001/api/countries/import' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer {token here}' \
--form 'file=@/D:/_countries.json'
```

P.S. I am using Windows 10 and git bash to run the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unsupported Media Type

Your action `public async Task<IActionResult> Import(IFormFile file)` expect `IFormFile`  parameter, but you sepecified request header with `Content-Type: application/json`, which cuase this issue.

Please try to specify the header to  `--header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'`, like below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This also can indicate a router problem.

Consider the following signature

```
[HttpGet("GetNearByPlaces")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetNearByPlaces(double lattitude, double longitude, IEnumerable<SearchPlaceType> types = null)
```

The framework is trying to decide that a path could exist based on lattitude longitude and types in THIS example.
However, IEnumerable is not supported (the path could have an undetermined number of arguments like /23.4/34.5/4/4/6/4) and thus a 415 is returned.

Modify the signature as follows will fix it.

```
        [HttpGet("GetNearByPlaces")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetNearByPlaces([FromQuery] double lattitude, [FromQuery] double longitude, [FromQuery] IEnumerable<SearchPlaceType> types = null)
```

Also a '[FromBody]' attribute could fix the problem.