# Upload JSON file to WebAPI

Tags: powershell, asp.net-core

I'm trying to upload a JSON file to a .Net Core 3 WebApp using Powershell Core, but can't get it to work. The 'file' is always null.

Below the code from the WebApp:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) 
        return BadRequest();

        var path = Path.GetTempFileName();
        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
        await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
        string FileName = file.FileName;

        // .. parsing the file

        return Ok();
}
```

And the actual request from Powershell:

```
$file = '/fileToUpload.json'
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'https://localhost:5001/uploadfile' -Method Post -InFile $file -ContentType 'application/json'
```

But this request always returns the following error:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

And when setting a breakpoint in the method, I can see that the 'file' is always null.

Initially I started with a method that accepts JSON data in the body, but there seems to be some sort of limitation in the body of a Post request when using Invoke-RestMethod, so I had to come up with another solution to work around this 'limit'. 
I am not running into a limit issue when using Postman though, so I guess it's related to a Powershell. In case anyone knows how to solve this 'body limit' issue, that would be even greater as I prefer posting the JSON data in the body instead of posting a file.

Hope someone can help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to use the full path, e. g. $file = 'D:\blabla\fileToUpload.json'

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I did use the full file path (just shortened it here for readability as I'm on macOS and the file path is a bit longer than d:\... ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I managed to solve my initial issue: the apparent payload limit of the body in a POST request when using the Invoke-RestMethod cmd-let. I switched using curl and now everything works as expected, so I don't have to post a file instead of the JSON data (which also seems to work fine now btw).

Here's the curl command I used for all that might run into the same issue:

```
curl --url 'https://localhost:5001/postJSON' --insecure -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --request POST --data @fileToUpload.json
```

Comment: For using curl command, you can refer to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207198/curl-415-unsupported-media-type/60223104#60223104).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use *-ContentType 'application/json* for uploading files.
[See Example 4: Simplified Multipart/Form-Data Submission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried using content-type 'multipart/form-data' and without providing a content-type, but in both situations I get the following error: 'Invoke-RestMethod : Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).'